# Boot receiver working on froyo but not on ICS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BroadcastReceivers in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892002/broadcastreceivers-in-ics)

I have a boot receiver that calls an other application on boot received,
this worked fine on froyo. but when i tried running it on ICS it does not work and the intent is  never called !
   This is the Boot Receiver registered in my manifest.

```
   <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is my Broadcast receiver class

public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, BootActivity.class);
          i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);


    }else{

    }
}}
```

why doesnt this work... is there any other way to make it work on ICS??

Comment: This was a security fix in Honeycomb and beyond, see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315325/can-android-application-have-only-broadcast-recevier-and-service-without-activit/12315565#12315565

Comment: if tats not possible then is there any other way to get this similar result??

Answer (score 0):

> Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user
>   explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this
>   state.
>
> As a result, when applications are first installed, they are totally ignored by the system until and unless the user manually
>   launches something: clicking on a launcher activity or adding an app
>   widget, most likely.
>
> Developers who had been relying upon getting some sort of system broadcast without user intervention will need to adjust their apps for
>   Android 3.1.

Comment: You need to manually start the app thru launcher... it is a security fix by the android guys!

Comment: what i'm actually trying to do is if my app is the present home app on boot up i want the receiver to call tat intent and i managed doin it on an older os.  any ideas on how i can accomplish this on ICS?

Comment: Due to security issues... you cant start an intent on boot.... you need to launch it using a launcher... THIS IS ONE OF THE CHANGES DONE IN API VERISONS 3.1 and ABOVE!!

Comment: @user1039013: "what i'm actually trying to do is if my app is the present home app on boot up" -- then delete your `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` and make your activity be a home screen. There is a Home sample app in your SDK samples.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have already done that.it is my home screen app now,but i want a particular intent to take place on system boot up if my app is the home screen app ...

Comment: @AdityaNikhade Thanks for the reply , i understand the security issue,but i want to know if there is an alternate method to do the same operation other than boot receiver?

Comment: i guess no! 

But you can launch your receiver thru a dummy activity which registers your receiver and then call finish();
It will look like nothing started but your receiver gets registered!

Comment: @user1039013: "i want a particular intent to take place on system boot up if my app is the home screen app" -- then have the home screen activity do that work when it appears. Otherwise, you will have to wait until the user does one of the things listed in this answer before your `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` will be able to work.

Comment: `@Override
 public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver,
   IntentFilter filter) {
  filter.addAction("BOOT_COMPLETED");
  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//    if(MyApplication.isActivityVisible() == true){
     if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
Intent i = new Intent(context, BootActivity.class);             i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);              context.startActivity(i);
}
}else{}
}
};
return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}  `

Comment: i registered the receiver like this in my home app in the main activity yet i do not receive the boot complete action...

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> missed this one :) now its working