# read received sms in a toast when sms is received

Tags: java, android

i want to design an android app which show the received sms in a android toast. 
i am using android studio with android 5.0 lolipop to compile. 
FOLLOWING are steps which i do to create app. ( all steps are from this site)

- create a new android project
- enter aplication name and location
- select minimum sdk as 'android 2.0'
- click on add 'no activity'
- create an SMSReceiver.java file under
  android->app->java->com.example......->SMSReceiver.java

with following code

```
package com.example.vaibhav.savemev1;
import java.lang.*;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml code is...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vaibhav.savemev1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

- click on 'android AVD' and 'wipe' out all data in android virtual device.
- click on play button and in edit configuration window 
  ->Activity->'do not launch Activity' radio button. click on it
- and ok
- chose device-> launch that device which data was wiped earlier

Still no success. Am i doing anythig wrong? The App is compiling successfully, but it does not show any toast when SMS is received.

Comment: Do you have any logging integrated to help debug this issue? If the `Toast` message is dependent on the `pdusObj`, then that seems to be problematic.

Comment: i replaced full  "public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)" code with just one single TOAST code. that is " Toast.makeText(context,"hi ! sms is received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" but still it does not show me the toast saying "hi ! sms is received" when sms is received.

Answer (score 0):

For a good answer: could you say how do you test? Do you use simulator and simulate SMS? If that so, you will need to set Data_SMS_RECEIVED in the AndroidManifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- extent another intent-filter -->
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:host="localhost" />
            <data android:host="16984" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

With this you can use ddms or simply telnet to send a SMS to the virtual Device. like so:

```
 telnet localhost 16984

 sms send <Hello World>
```

text **with** brackets should appear. This just works with Virtual Devices. On Device the Telephony SMS_RECEIVED should do the trick.

If it not work, you should use logcat and post information form there.

Comment: i replaced my <receiver > with exactly you have told in ur comment. i just changed the port number from 16984 to 5554. but still no success. and logcat is empty.

Comment: and i use telnet to send sms to my virtual device which is provided to me by android studio.

Comment: I found that issue: You are just implementing a BroadcastReceiver, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315325/can-android-application-have-only-broadcast-recevier-and-service-without-activit

Comment: ya right. so there is no way to install BroadcastReceiver in start state ? as per @hashire said in the above link.